# Proper way to implement grid filtering and sorting on a custom column

Tags: magento-1, grid, filter, sorting

I have a custom grid with products. It shows `price` and `special_pirce`. Now I want to add another colum which is discount percentage.

I have added the column discount with a custom render. The renderer just does a calculation based on both prices and returns the dicount. So far so good.

Add column:

```
$this->addColumn('discount', array(
            'header'        => $helper->__('Discount'),
            'type'          => 'number',
            'align'         => 'right',
            'index'         => 'discount',
            'renderer'      => 'AM_Grid_Block_Adminhtml_Purchased_Renderer_Discount',
            'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_discountFilter'),
));
```

Renderer:

```
function render(Varien_Object $row)
{
    $price = $row->getData('price');
    $specialPrice = $row->getData('special_price');

    if(isset($specialPrice)) {
        return $discount = round(($specialPrice / $price) * 100, 0);
    }
}
```

Now I am struggeling with the proper way to implement filtering and sorting on this column. I found plenty of examples which just do filtering based on normal column values using mySQL operaters or such. The problem is my value needs to be calculated first so I can't use mySQL operators.

- I know I need to use `filter_condition_callback` for filtering. How should this method look? Is there a best practice how this works in conjunction with a renderer?
- How do I implement sorting?